# Referencing the item in a with statement

Tags: vb.net, list, with-statement

I have some controls that I am adding to a panel. I also want to add the controls to a list so I can index them. I can't figure out how to refer to the item in the with statement so I don't have to explicitly add each control to the list. Is this possible, or do I have to add them separately?

Example:

```
dim label1 as new label
dim mylist as listof(of Objects)
with label1
    .top = 50
    .left = 100
    .text = "Something"
    mylist.add([this label object])
end with
```

without having to do:

```
mylist.add(label1)
```

Because I have a lot of objects that I am looping through and I don't want to have to explicitly add each item if I don't have to.

Comment: Why inside the With? Not list of Object (not Objects) but at least Control. This will save boxing and unboxing when you want to access the controls. How about a list for each type of control so you can have access to all the properties without casting.

Comment: @Mary because that won't work for what I am doing. If it can't be done within the "with" statement, then it would defeat the purpose of efficiently adding them and I would be back to adding them explicitly.

Comment: The With statement is for accessing properties and calling methods on the object referenced. You want to call a method on the list. Wherever you are adding your controls to the Controls collection you could add them to your list in the same manner

Comment: I don't think you can. But you already have to name the variable inside the With statement, why would it reduce efficiency if you also specify it in the add? If you really need it, you could do "With addLabelToList(myList)"  then, addLabelToList would add the label to the list and return the object.

Comment: Would you be interested in `mylist.Add(New Label With {.Top = 50, .Left = 50, .Text = "Something"})`?

Comment: So it looks like the answer is basically "no". Although @Andrew Morten, while I've never seen a with statement used that way, it would probably work. It's not that major, but it would be a heck of a lot easier to copy and paste "mylist.add(me)" with me being the object in the with statement, than mylist.add(label name) to over 100 labels and having to type in each name.

Comment: Are these objects on painted on a form? If so, forms are containers and you don't need to add the controls to a list because they are already on the form's list of controls.

Comment: @John Perhaps if you explained the layer above what you've asked we could give more useful suggestions. Usually needing over 100 labels on a form would indicate the UI could be improved in some way, but not always.